# How to sum part of a vector in `cvxpy`?

Tags: python, cvxpy

I am using `cvxpy` to solve a convex optimization problem, and here's my constraint:

[image]

So how can I express this constraint in `cvxpy`? The [`sum_entries`](http://www.cvxpy.org/en/latest/tutorial/functions/index.html#scalar-functions) function in `cvxpy` can only sum the whole matrix/vector, but not part of a vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just select a subset by using indexing (in the following example: classic python-based slicing; but more complex indexing / numpy-style is possible):

Example:

```
from cvxpy import *

x = Variable(5)
constraints = []
constraints.append(x >= 0)   # all vars
constraints.append(x <= 10)  # all vars
constraints.append(sum_entries(x[:3]) <= 3)  # only part of vector; sum(first-three) <=3
objective = Maximize(sum_entries(x))
problem = Problem(objective, constraints)
problem.solve()
print(problem.status)
print(x.value.T)
```

Output:

```
optimal
[[  1.   1.   1.  10.  10.]]
```

I also suspect you are misunderstanding the problem here, but that formula-image is of course incomplete to be implemented.

Comment: Thanks it works! But I got a `Problem does not follow DCP rules.` now :<. Do you know what the problem is? [here](https://gist.github.com/hkalexling/17eba1f64a6d0907f181abbc5b8f1436)'s the gist

Comment: @AlexLing Work through cvxpy's docs to understand what the whole DCP-idea is. Some remarks: (1) cvxpy can only formulate and solve problems according to DCP-rules (2) Those DCP rules can only formulate convex optimization problems (3) Not all convex problems can be formulated by DCP rules (4) The general decision-problem: is this problem convex is NP-hard (5) The DCP-approach is somewhat a proof by construction: if valid DCP -> proof of convexity. So: make sure your prob is convex (context? paper?) Yes, you have to change the formulation / sometimes the natural formulation fails. Not? No cvxpy